# How can I trigger multiple TeamCity builds based on the Artifact Dependencies of another build?

Tags: teamcity

I have a TeamCity build (build config A) that outputs a set of files (up to 100). Each of these files needs to be processed by a second TeamCity build configuration (build config B). I can set up an Artifact Dependency to trigger a single build of B when the files are created. What I am trying to figure out is how to have a build triggered for each file, so a build of A triggers 100 builds of B, and each build of B gets a single file from the output artifacts of A. Is this possible?

I believe I can do this using the API, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Thanks,
Erick

Comment: The only way to achieve this would be through the API. Do you still need a solution for that?

Comment: That is too bad. I know how to use the API to do it, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried defining the 100 builds each separately, each having an artifact dependency with an artifact rule matching the one file you're interested in? Granted, generating 100 build configs may be painful, but in Kotlin this should be doable.